# Polymer Project Structure : Cannot nest files

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

I have a Polymer application and I would like to clean my code and gathered elements into subfolders.

Here is my actual project structure :

[image: Project Struct]

And I would like to do something like this :

[image]

So I redo my import (since it's nested i need to ad some '../' and some 'alert-page/' where needed)
But it doesn't work,  the element shows up well but is empty of data (every field is empty:
[image: alert-page empty]

And I have those error appearing in the logs :

[image: chrome error]

And I don't get why?

Have a nice day :)

Comment: I can only think of that you missed an import somewhere... as subfolders definitely work.
Maybe check the network panel for 404s? or duplicate loaded files?

Comment: I agree.. I'll retry properly and I'll see, thanks for your answer

Comment: Can you please add code snippet?